# linux driver development: How does docker make sure app version matches kernel version?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, version

On linux, when I wish to develop a driver(character device or block device),I'll need to make sure I develop upon corresponding kernel version. Each linux distribution like centos6.8 has its kernel version like 2.6.32

But seems on docker, all images share the same, new kernel version of moby4.9.2. So it seems that only develop normal applications on docker is valid, but not programs like drivers or any management applications that should visit /dev or other system level resources.

So is docker linux designed to develop system program? If there's no way to specify which kernel version and device structure should be used, seems docker is only for normal user applications?

My question is: how to develop programs like drivers on docker and apply to production linux distributions?